# Adding elements in a Varray

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, varray

I'm working on Oracle. If I have table in which one of the attributes is a Varray, like :

```
create type list_surname as Varray(20) of varchar2(15)
/

create table employes(name varchar2(15),
                      ls_pnm list_surname,
                      adrprivate Tadresse,
                      adrprof REF Tadresse);
```

Is it possible to add or modify elements containing in an existing ls_pnm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
UPDATE employees
  SET ls_pnm = list_surname('<list of values>')
 WHERE name ='<conditions>';
```

Comment: would that add to the existing values or overwrite the existing ones ?

Comment: In fact, this will overwrite the existing list of values. What i'd like to do is to add up to the existing values.

Comment: Just concatenate to the existing values, what's stopping you? `UPDATE employees set ls_pnm = ls_pnm || list_surname('<list of values>') WHERE name ='<conditions>';`